# cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv8-a" for aarch64 compiling

Tags: cmake, arm, cortex-a

I need to adapt a series of codes and scripts written for raspberry Pi (1st gen) (that was running a ARM11 cpu) to run on a Allwinner H6-based board cpu (an ARM Cortex-A53).

I already substituted `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR` from `ARCH armv7l` to `ARCH aarch64`.
But, to launch the cmake compiling command string I had

```
cmake -D CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-march=armv7-a" /..path
```

and I thought to substitute the `-march=armv7-a` with `-march=armv8-a`.

Now my doubt is: could be this correct to compile for the Allwinner H6 64bit? Why I can't put directly `aarch64` instead of `armv8-a`? And, finally: what the difference between "armv8" and "armv8-a"?.

Sorry, I am a little bit confused here.

Comment: `cmake` is a utility which configures you build system. The `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are flags passed to your compiler. Refer to your compiler documentation to decipher the meaning of the flags. cmake has little to do here, it just passes the `march` option to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

1. 1) Yes, `-march=armv8-a` would be correct but less specific than,
   say, `-mtune=cortex-a53`, since the Allwinner H6 is a cortex-a53.
2. My guess is that you cannot put `-march=aarch64` instead of `-march=arm-v8-a` because this would be too generic: after all, you can already specify  `‘armv8-a’, ‘armv8.1-a’, ‘armv8.2-a’, ‘armv8.3-a’, ‘armv8.4-a’ and  ‘armv8.5-a’`, as documented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AArch64-Options.html).
3. armv8 is the umbrella name for `ARMv8-A`, `ARMv8-M` and `ARMv8-R`. A, R and M are 'profiles' according to arm terminology, and target different types of applications: 
   See [here](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/a-profile), [here](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/m-profile) and [here](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/cpu-architecture/r-profile) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! It's absolutely better now!

Comment: I am glad to read it helped.  You may want to accept the response if you are happy with it.